# Does POSTGRES have a "autocomplete" query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about Postgres. For example I want to query a column but I only fill in the first letters. Am I able to get all the results with these letters?

Comment: Exactly what are you looking for? Autocompleting elements of your query, or performing a prefix-search on a column?

Comment: Automatically completing column names in a query, if that's what you're talking about, would be a feature of the client software you use to connect to PostgreSQL, not a feature of PostgreSQL itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgres enterprise manager tool, I think you can see the suggestions using `ctrl+spacebar`